# How to convert a list of decimal numbers into a single plottable coordinate

Tags: numbers, formula, equation

I have a dataset and i need to apply Support Vector Machine for that. The dataset has total of 50 instances and each instance will be like below,

```
9164.254    6719.5293   4883.4487   3718.159    2015.2214   5569.907    3849.0588   2793.3875   7017.734    4802.2524
```

Here during the SVM process I have to convert each instance into coordinates to be plotted in graph. But my instances all have decimal values. How can i convert the list of values into a plottable coordinate of format (x, y)? Is there any formula or algorithm for this?

Comment: What is your exact use-case? Why do you want to plot your values?

Comment: Im trying to plot each instance on a data as a point. I have 50 instances (rows) with each instance having 100 values. i want to convert this 100 values into a single coordinate so i will get 50 coordinates for 50 instances.